# DAX -- Cannot get TOPN formula to give me sum of the top n

Tags: dax, summarize, top-n

I've spend hours pouring over documentation on SUMMARIZE, SUMMARIZECOLUMNS, ADDCOLUMNS AND TOPN, and I just cannot get this simple calculation to come out correctly.  I've even looked at results with DAX Studio, and it's always wrong.  I'm trying to do this the "right way," i.e., without using deprecated techniques like using SUMMARIZE to add columns.  The problem is simple and classic: summarize a sales table by Salesman, and add up the sales for the top N.  Here's some data.  I presume I need to calculate an intermediate summary table -- but maybe that's not necessary?

[image: sample data, and desired result]

If someone could just layout the DAX code, I'd greatly appreciate it!  I've tried everything!

Here's my code:

```
Top N Acc Rev.. = 
var N = MAX( 'Numbers'[RankNum] )
VAR CaseTable = SaleData
VAR Table0 = SUMMARIZE( CaseTable, [Salesman], [Sale])
VAR Table1 = TOPN(N, Table0, [Salesman], DESC)
RETURN
    SUMX( Table1, [Sale] )
```

The data wasn't as complex as it should be.  I also had a mistake of ranking by Salesman versus ranking by Salesman's total sales in the TOPN function.  So here is my new data and code which finally works. The results for N = 1 or 2 are 625 and 1127.  Thanks, Jos Wooley!

[image]

```
SaleTest = 
VAR N = MAX(Numbers[RankNum])
VAR CaseTable = Filter(SalesData, [Sale] > 100 )
VAR Table0 = SUMMARIZE(CaseTable, [Salesman], "Sales", SUM( SalesData[Sale] ) )
VAR Table1 = TOPN(N, Table0, [Sales], DESC)
RETURN SUMX( Table1, [Sales] )
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `SUMMARIZE` be `VAR Table0=SUMMARIZE(CaseTable,[Salesman],"Sales",SUM(SaleData[Sale]))`?

Comment: If I use that, I get an error, SaleData[Sale] is underlined in red with messages "Cannot find name 'Sale', and also "Parameter is not the correct type."  My code actually has some filters on SalesData, so I think I want to only reference CaseTable, not SaleData, in the rest of the code.  When I use SUM(CasetTable[Sale]) I again get "Parameter is not the correct type" error--I don't understand that at all.  When I use SUMX(CaseTable,[Sale]), I get the sum of the filtered values X N. (Even if I wrap that or the Summarize in Calculate or CalculateTable -- every variation is the same.

Comment: I've revised the data and code above.

Comment: I'm also trying to avoid using Summarize to add columns. There is a lot of advice out there not to do that, although it's rather confusing. (Even if you've read the Definitive Guide to DAX cover-to-cover as I have--but obviously I need to reread some sections!)  E.g., The rule is never add extended columns by using SUMMARIZE, unless it is required due to
1. You want to use ROLLUP over grouping columns to obtain subtotals, or 2. You are using non-trivial table expressions in the extended column.

Comment: Freond sorry I did not understand what was the question here. Do you want a Dax measure that returns the top 2/3 salesman based on the total sales?

Comment: Yes, total each salesman's sales (over 100 with the edit I added), and then produce the sum of the top N.

Comment: Thanks, Jos Wooley.  I finally got this to work, using your suggestion.  Another problem is that I had the sort field wrong in TOPN.  I find it very odd that the SUM is from SalesDate, not CaseTable, the table being summarized.  I don't understand that at all -- very counterintuitive (which must mean I'm missing something fundamental!).

Comment: Refer to this extremely elegant answer [Here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-to-filter-table-based-on-TOPN-aggregation/m-p/2245897#M817680). This question genuinely bothered me which is why I ended up asking at the best place possible. Thanks for this one.